# How to access activity public properties

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can anyone explain how to access public properties of another activity. I call second activity from first activity and i set some public properties as shown below. Nevertheless if it comes to those lines:

```
string doggy =  nextActivity.myDog;         //myDog prop not accessible from here
string text = nextActivity.myText;          //myText prop not accessible from here
```

those properties are not accessible. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong, should it be done diffrently in xamarin?

```
[Activity(Label = "FirstActivity")]
public class FirstActivity : Activity
{
    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Intent nextActivity = SecondActivity.CreateIntent(this, new Dog() {Ngnameofdog = "Sonia"}, 100 );
           StartActivity(nextActivity);

           string doggy =  nextActivity.myDog;          //myDog prop not accessible from here
           string text = nextActivity.myText;           //myText prop not accessible from here
        }
}

[Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
        public static Dog myDog { get; set; }
        public static string myText { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.third);
        }

        public static Intent CreateIntent(Context context, Dog dog, int rowID)
        {
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(context, typeof(SecondActivity));
            myDog = new Dog("Sonia");
            myText = rowID.ToString();
            return nextActivity;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDog` and `myText` are static properties. This means that there is only one instance per application, no matter how many instances of `SecondActivity` you have.

They can be accessed using the class name, i.e. `SecondActivity.myDog` and `SecondActivity.myText`. If you want to have a different instance of `myDog` and `myText` per `SecondActivity`, just remove the `static` label.

Comment: you right i forgot, but if i would create public property it wouldn't be visible,can you explain why?

Comment: @Arie Which property are you setting to public and which class are you trying to access it from?

Comment: ok i think i made it - i changed my static method to not statis - CreateIntent, then in First Activity i did:
          var nextActivity = new ThirdActivity();
            nextActivity.Somethnig = "textValue";

            var intent = nextActivity.CreateIntent(this, new Dog() { nameOfDog = "Sonia" }, 100);

            StartActivity(intent);

            var dog = nextActivity.myDog;
            var text = nextActivity.myText;
            var ssss = nextActivity.Somethnig;